# Ideal way to organize Java constants

Tags: java, coding-style, constants, code-organization

We have a huge projects based on an old jdk 1.4. We have migrated the web app to JDK 1.6 but still lot of inefficient practices and bad design exist in the code.

On of the major pain point huge java classes 2500+ lines of code in single java file. So many files like these.

In an attempt to refactor the classes I had started off by removing constants and putting constants in different Constants.java file. but since there are so many constants through-out the application, the constants file has the risk of growing to humongous proportions.

I would appreciate feedback on what strategy are developers adopting to keep code clean and maintainable.

Comment: A single `Constants` class sounds like an antipattern. Split them up depending on what the constants mean, or replace them with enums where appropriate.

Comment: What specific problems are you trying to solve? Just the fact that files are too big? If that's it, then the cost of refactoring everything won't be worth it.

Comment: Its not just length/size of file. Its violation of responsibilities of each class as well as class representing multiple contracts. A bean class for storing home page values ( a Model ) also creates and handles caching structures for html templates.. This is just one example

Comment: Maybe you could put the constants in internal `static final` classes, so you can group them together, and fold them within your IDE. Afterwards, you can split these classes out of the class where they came from, and implement them as classes with real functionality.

Comment: http://thecodelesscode.com/case/178

Answer (score 21):

Keep your constants in the class they are related to, don't feel obligated to extract them. It may clean up the code of the class, but mixing unrelated constants in a file is not an improvement.

**Keep things related together**.

And also you can convert them to **Enums** when possible/useful (but that can require some refactoring).

Comment: But then there is always a risk of duplicate values for the constants. eg table name "user_profile" is stored in multiple constants like EMPLOYER_USER_PROFILE and WEB_USER_PROFILE. etc.

Comment: Why can't you store the table name as a constant in the DAO class (the class for that table), and then use that constant from the other classes? (it requires declaring the constant as public)

Comment: @RegMem you can use checkstyle and possibly other static code analysers to find identical strings and put a warning (or an 'informational', as I use) tag on the duplicates.

Answer (score 15):

Putting all the Constants in a single file is a terrible idea! Especially the uber-Constant anti-pattern where all the Constants are in an `Interface` that every class has to `implement`. 10 ways to Sunday terrible! This was a bad idea when people started doing it back in the early 1990's before Java! It is definitely a bad idea in 2012!

It means you are mingling lots of un-related information and creating un-needed dependencies everytime you import this uber-Constants file. Things that go together should be together in an `Enum` or at least in the `Class` that uses them as arguments to its methods so that when they are changed you know how to do an impact analysis easily.

Imagine `Color` constants mixed in with `DaysOfTheWeek` constants mixed in with other business domain constants and there will be hundreds if not thousands of these things in a single file. How can that ever be considered a good idea? In every non-contrived case, an `Enum` that is a `public inner` member of a `Class` is a better solution.

It also means you have a single flat namespace to try and create names that don't conflict, then they aren't obvious what they belong to and how they should be used. This is never a positive exercise.

When designing and refactoring you should always:

Strive for **high cohesion**, this means keep related things as close together as possible.

Strive for **loose coupling** this means don't let un-related things leak into other un-related scopes.

Strive for self-documenting maintainable code, dozens or hundreds of `private static final String/int` declarations all mixed together doesn't fit this definition by anyone's standard!

In 2012 C-style constants are a poor solution when you now have `Enum` as a tool, you should be focused on converting as many of these groups of Constants to `Enum` wherever possible. `Enum` is type safe and can have other attributes and properties and behaviors attached to it to make them `intelligent`. That is the path to go down.

Comment: Perhaps it's useful to add what makes things "related": they are likely to *change together* without causing (too many) changes to unrelated things.

Comment: (Just because constants are in an `interface`, doesn't mean that that interface *has* to be implemented.)

Comment: Cohesion is the term I was looking for :) working on a project that has constants.py files as a standard :/

Answer (score 3):

For someone who is visiting this page.

If you don't want to maintain multiple constant files, below is the better way to organize.

```
public interface Constants {
    public static final String CREATE_USER = "createUser";
    // Nested Interface.
    public interface ProjectConstants {
        public static final String CREATE_PROJECT = "createProject";
        public static final String INVALID_SESSION = "Invalid Session";
        // As you know they are implicity public static final.
    }
}// Accessed as: 
Constants.ProjectConstants.CREATE_PROJECT
```

Updates:

As a best practice, its better to use Class.(See comments. . Thanks keplerian.)

```
public final class Constants {

    private Constants() {
        // restrict instantiation
    }

    public static final double PI = 3.14159;
    public static final double PLANCK_CONSTANT = 6.62606896e-34;
}

import static Constants.PLANCK_CONSTANT;
import static Constants.PI;

public class Calculations {

    public double getReducedPlanckConstant() {
        return PLANCK_CONSTANT / (2 * PI);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just putting constants in a `Constant.java` file doesn't make sens in my opinion (it just move the problem away). But sometimes I use to regroup them to clear the things and use several files to regroup them : `DatabaseConstants.java`, `GraphicConstants.java` and so on...
and of course, using enums can be useful too (and best practice).

edit : to be precise, I actually work with Java ME application, so it's just a way to "mimic" the enums I can't have, with a "controlled vocabulary" in abstract classes (I miss all the Java EE features...)

Comment: I was thinking of using this strategy, but my question does not reflect that because I was still debating whether to adopt that strategy. An app that has upward of 150 Model unique objects ( no we are not using Spring, or struts etc ). each of these model objects have a plethora of constants scattered all over, but its an approach

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to share a design pattern for constants i've seen a few years ago that maybe can help.

Start by creating a BaseConstant file.  This will hold all your global constants that all packages could use.

Now in each subpackage of your app create a Constants file that will only be related to the subpackage . So if you had . a subpackage called Login only put constants related to login there. But the key is to extend off of BaseConstants. this way you get to see all the global constants in the IDE chooser but when you open the file you only see your package constants.  that being said i think constant files can get really heavy and duplicate values and hard to read.

Here is what i mean ..

```
public class BaseConstants{

public static final String GLOBAL1= "GLOBAL string"; 

public static final String GLOBAL2= "another GLOBAL string"; 
}
```

Now in all your other packages create a files like this:

```
class MyPackageConstants extends BaseConstants{

public static final String LOCAL1 = "local String"
public static final String LOCAL2= "ANOTHER LOCAL string"; 
}
```

in your IDE when you type "MyPackageConstants." you should see all the constants for the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of putting all of the constants to a single java file. The best way is to put the constants accossiated with the classes in themselves, but name them with capital letter and underscores like this one: EXAMPLE_CONSTANT

Comment: Not my downvote, but the problem is when constants are needed by more than one class, i.e. the constants are to do with interactions between classes, not the internal behaviour of classes

Comment: @DNA then you put them in the most logical class and make them public.

Comment: @owlstead that's easy to say, but there may not be a "most obvious class". When multiple classes rely on constants to collaborate, they all share those constants equally, and there is no way to decide which one should contains them. That doesn't imply that _all_ constants should go in _one_ file of course. Just that shared constants might be best in  a shared interface. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html for example

Comment: @DNA You are right regarding the fact that you might want to create a separate class if the constants are shared. It's a terrible example, if only for the name of the interface (nothing about orientation in the name), and the fact that it *is* an interface instead of a `final` class with a `private` constructor (I think this is in "Effective Java" somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Enums for all of your constants?  I've been told it is the preferred way since Java 1.5.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html

Comment: Enums are great, but they are not always able to replace constants - each one should be used when applicable.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you have multiple java files over 2500 LOCs, the decision where to put the constants should be the least of your problems. You should form a clear picture of how the restructured system will look like. 
This is probably much harder then deciding where to stick the constants and other syntactic considerations but needs to be done first nevertheless.

Comment: Ok, to put this another way, once you have a design in place, the constant question is likely to go away.